# Proving an inequality by induction.

Tags: calculus, inequality

**Question:** If $n\ge2$, prove that $n!/n^n\le(1/2)^k$, where k is the greatest integer $\le(n/2)$.

**My answer:** It is clear that statement is true for $n=2$

*Inductive step:* $n\ge2 \Rightarrow (1/2)\ge(1/n)$ and we granted that $n!/n^n\le(1/2)^k$.

$\Rightarrow$ $n!/n^{n+1}\le(1/2)^{k+1}$.

There is also another fact that $(n+1)!/(n+1)^{n+1}\le n!/n^{n+1}$

$\Rightarrow$ $(n+1)!/(n+1)^{n+1}\le (1/2)^{k+1}$

This completes the proof by induction.

**I can't be sure about the deduction that I've made in fifth line, I can't decide whether the sign should be $\le$  or $\lt$**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reasonably straight forward proof. We have
$$e^x=1+x+\dfrac{x^2}2 + \cdots + \dfrac{x^n}{n!} + \cdots$$
Hence, we have
$$e^n=1+n+\dfrac{n^2}2 + \cdots + \dfrac{n^n}{n!} + \cdots$$
This means we obtain
$$e^n > \dfrac{n^n}{n!} \implies \dfrac{n!}{n^n} < \left(\dfrac1e\right)^n$$
which is much tighter than the bound you want.

Comment: This is not the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks okay $\le$ but anyhow is does not matter as you only wanted to prove the weaker version with $\le$

So even if in reality that was a stricter $<$, it would not have mattered for the conclusion

Comment: I am not sure also about the inequality itself.

Comment: @feynman if you take for granted the two "facts" you've written, then the proof is correct. Those facts should be proved of course but that's not the question I suppose

Comment: I've done it intuitively, can you provide its proof by editing your answer?